# Eclipse marking JavaFX packages as missing although they're added to the build path

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, runtimeexception, modulenotfounderror

Today I started having a look into JavaFX using this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bC4XB6JAaoU). At first everything worked fine, however when I tried launching the project, there was some error which had to do with the project not being able to find javafx.controls. As I accidently created the `module-info.java` in the beginning which was not done in the tutorial, I thought this might be the issue and deleted the project in order to create a new one.

However, after doing this, I can't even get the project into an executable state, no matter if I create `module-info.java` or not. I saved the `JavaFX` files in a separate location, so that it wasn't deleted when deleting the project. Hence, it is still available through the created User Library. But the errors in the code, indicating Eclipse is not able to resolve the referenced classes, don't disappear when I add the User Library:
[image]

I retried several times, sometimes with `module-info.java`, sometimes without, sometimes closing Eclipse inbetween, etc. but I couldn't get the errors to disappear and I just can't find any meaningful reason why this might happen, as I did the exact same things as right at the first try where the errors actually disappeared.

Currently, when trying to launch the application, I get the following error message:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module JavaFXTest not found
```

It seems that Eclipse is actually unable to find the actual project, but I don't get why this error might happen?

Is there anything I'm missing here that could cause this problem? Also, I added the runtime `args`  as mentioned in the tutorial (`--module-path "<my installation path\lib>" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`), but still got an error when trying this for the first time, saying it was unable to find javafx.controls but in the tutorial everything seemed to work. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: when Eclipse doesn't find _my own_ module, there's typically some stale state in the project - clean the project, delete runtime configs often help

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I just tried this but unfortunately it doesn't seem like it did help in solving the problem. Also, shouldn't such stale state in the project be resolved when deleting it and creating a new one? Because I also tried this several times to no avail.